# Returning user input from google forms in an email using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on trying to get a form to print a SKU every time a google form is submitted for a product. I have gotten as far as getting an email to send every time a form is submitted, but i can't quite figure out how to get  it to read out specific data in the email.

I have several questions that the user answers in the google form in order to determine the SKU and now i need to just output specific values that the user input, but i cant find the syntax on how to do it for google apps script. I dont have a lot of coding experience (a handful of C and C++ courses) and am really struggling.

here is what i have that returns the email on form submit:

```
function setUpTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendConfirmationEmail')
  .forForm('1dLL_1KJEjVddK3x3SFEBxckccPRB5Ooz0OeBPn5xB7I')
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}

function sendConfirmationEmail(e) {
  const recipient = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  const subject = "SKU";
  const body = 'Your SKU is';
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: `e.values.join(',')` would print them all out in a csv string.

Comment: Please provide an example namedValues array and show how you want it displayed in your email